# How made this Android view element

Tags: android, html, android-view

What are you think, how it's made (the table)?

[image]

Comment: Yes. Its table with border and gavity left :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simply accomplished in a layout without using any image. Always use table layout for creating Rows*Columns.

[image]
Here is your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3d92ff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:text="100"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BenchPress"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="21sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:text="Repeats"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="Weight"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="%"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="125.5"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="100%"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="125.5"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="100%"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="125.5"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="100%"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="125.5"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="100%"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="125.5"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="100%"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="125.5"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="100%"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="125.5"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3d92ff"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:text="100%"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    background-color: #00BFFF;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
}
```

And html:

```
<table width="500px" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
    <td>Table Cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Something like this..

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableLayout
    android:background="#000000">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <TextView

            android:background="#606060"
            android:text="text" />

        ...               

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```